# Aligning label with a background image

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have created a checkbox constructed of a div with checkbox image background and a label.

Html:

```
<div class="checkbox checked" ></div>
<label class="label">Some text</label>
```

and css:

```
.checkbox
{
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    float:left;
    background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/uidesignicons/checkbox_yes.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

The problem is - the label is not aligned with the image, it sits slightly below the baseline of the image div and that looks ugly. You can see the jsfiddle of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/muzzzy/3hUGV/5/

How can I align them, given that I can't specify absolute values for padding or line-height, because this is really a part of a javascript plugin that converts regular checkboxes, so labels can be of different font sizes.

UPDATE: I'm also including the image of how it looks now:

[image]

I'd like the text to be vertically centered with the center of the image

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? It looks correct to me (IE9)

Comment: If the labels can be different sizes then it'd have to dynamically move, so you may want to just set that in the plug-in.

Comment: @James - I added the image of how my Chrome is displaying it (I see the same on IE8 and FF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be better off swapping out your `div.checkbox` for a `span`, and then setting the `span` to `display:inline-block`. This way, you can use `vertical-align:middle` on the elements to get them centered (The only rare cases vertical-align has a use!)

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3hUGV/34/

Answer (score 4):

If you dont care about older browsers, drop the `float: left` and try using `display: inline-block;` on the div.checkbox. After that, play with the vertical-align attribute.

Then do some cross-browser because for some of us it already looks ok!

Here the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/karameloso/hQ2uK/

Answer (score 0):

Well for what you're asking, try a table: http://jsfiddle.net/3rRb6/

(Unless of course, you're one of those *omg-im-not-using-a-table-for-layout!@$#?@$!?!* type of people)

Comment: The problem is not in using tables; as I mentioned I need to solve this problem in teh context of a js plugin I'm writing to substitute real checkboxes and their labels, and the original label might not be right next to the original checkbox, so I can't use anything that ties them together.